# Symbol Load Information menu not displaying for Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, visual-studio, json.net

When I am stepping through the example C# code from AtTask API, I get to the line in code(in Visual Studio) where it reads

```
return JObject.Parse(body);
```

At this point, VS tries to find, not sure what, pdb files or source code files, I am confused even after reading all the SO posts on here about **Source not Found**
I know there are extensive posts on SO about **Source Not Found** in Visual Studio. Except none of them resolve my issues. I am using VS 2013 Community Edition. I am stepping through C# sample source code from this link [attask code samples](https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/code-samples/)

I am providing a hyperlink to a TechSmith Jing SWF video. It shows all the relevant images, like my directory path to bin and debug and how they contain pdb files for both JSON.NET as well as the executeable. 
[Jing video displaying the SOURCE NOT FOUND error](http://www.screencast.com/t/PHwuwVritzGG)

The following is an image of my solution tree taken from VS, also depcting the Properites Window information for the Newtonsoft dll. 
[Newtsoft dll location on disk](http://www.screencast.com/t/FJGHKAyf5)

Comment: Is your code throwing an exception at this point and are you loading symbols from a remote server?  Usually, VS is only going to ask for source if it is trying to step into the method, or if there's an exception occurring in a module with symbols loaded.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I did a step over on that line and it returned by throwing an JsonReaderException. The exception message is Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Line 1, position 1. In light of the Json documentation on the Parse method http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm the Parse method is designed to parse a Json object NOT HTML.

Comment: Looks like you may want to close this question, and open a new one with why your API call is returning HTML.  I'm not familiar with that API though.

Comment: Thank you Steve for your help, I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why VS was asking for JObject.cs Source Code is because the Parse() method is throwing an JsonReaderException while trying to parse the returned HTML. I am creating a new question asking why the AtTask API call returns HTML instead of JSON.